# ASP.net MVC 3 Ajax.beginform update and Client Side validation Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation, ajax.beginform

I am trying to update the partialview in which i used ajax.beginform. normally, first time it validate on client side but when i refresh the partial view innerHTML using outside button event, it is no more doing clientside validation on button submit.

It is working fine in google chrome but it is not working in IE 8, 9 or Mozilla.

Please find below link to download the sample project that i have created.

[Download Sample](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1940033/temp/AjaxUpdatesDemo.zip)

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to solve this situation.

Change 1
As on the sample project i referenced 
two jquery scripts called Jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobstusive.js on layout page but i didnt reference those jquery script file on my partial view.

Change 2

instead of updating the content of ajax.beginform in partialview, we need to update the container of ther partialview which is $("#dvPartialData").html(result) in Index view of home controller.